# Package wrapfig with many section and subsections

Tags: sectioning, floats, wrapfigure

I'm using package `wrapfig` in a document with many subsections. At least one per page. I have a tall figure, almost the height of an entire page, so I assume `wrapfig` is the correct way to place this - one column of text (~60% of page width) and one column of figure (~40% of page width).

However, `wrapfig` appears to have issues when it extends over a section or subsection. There have been two ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61650/wrapfig-and-page-breaks-after-section-heading), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120926/prevent-wrapfigure-from-wrapping-the-next-section)) questions on this site have brought this up already, but the answer to both of those is "put the new section on the next page". Since I have many sections, that does not work in this document.

Perhaps the solution is to embed the `wrapfig` in another environment, but I am not sure which one.

## Edit

I found what was causing the issue:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
```

Here is an MWE. It should generate the screenshot below. Comment out the above line, and `wrapfig` appears to work correctly.

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}  % disables section and subsection numbering
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.30\linewidth}
  \rule{5cm}{9cm}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:fig}
\end{wrapfigure}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have. Not sure how to do two columns that are not 50/50, but I'm also interested in this specific answer because sometimes the image is only 1/2 or 2/3 of the page height, and this problem still exists, but two full columns would leave a lot of whitespace in that situation.

Comment: Please make a complete small document that shows the problem (you can use `\rule{2cm}{10cm}` or whatever you need instead of `\includegraphics` to make a portable test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Interesting,

You can patch the section handling so that things work:

Add

```
\makeatletter
\def\patchsect#1\let\@svsec\@empty{#1\def\@svsec{\leavevmode\kern1sp\relax}}
\let\old@sect\@sect
\def\@sect{\expandafter\patchsect\old@sect}
\makeatother
```

However if your real document is using numbered sections like this, setting `secnumdepth` to -1 and using numbers in the section titles is just the wrong thing to do, it disables all LaTeX's mechanisms for cross referencing.  See [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136527/section-numbering-without-numbers/136528#136528)

Comment: Thanks. I would never manually number sections. That was just a bad example. Is this a bug? Where would I report it?